# URL parsing in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have an inconsistent url in of the tables.

The sample looks like

https://blue.decibal.com.au/Transact?pi=9024&pai=2&ct=0&gi=1950&byo=true&ai=49&pa=289&ppt=0

or

https://www.google.com/Transact?pi=9024&pai=2&ct=0&gi=1950&byo=true&ai=49&pa=289&ppt=0

or

https3A%google.com/Transact?pi=9024&pai=2&ct=0&gi=1950&byo=true&ai=49&pa=289&ppt=0

For the first URL "blue" is the result but it comes with two domains blue and decibal.
Second one is google.
Third is again google.

My requirement is to parse the url and match it with a look table with domain name which contains blue, google, bing etc.

However, the inconstancy in the URL that's stored in DB is a challenge. Need to write a sql which can identify the match and if there are two domain just pick the first one. The URL can be a sit and not expected to be a standard one.

Appreciate some help.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Select Ls.Initial_referrer, LIR.Master_Source , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LS.Widesales_Lead_ID ORDER BY LIR.Master_Source ASC) as rn
from xxx.STAGING.STG_ALL_SALES_LEADS LS
INNER JOIN WIDEBILL.REFERENCE_DATA.LKP_INITIAL_REFERRER LIR
    ON POSITION(lower(LIR.INITIAL_REFERRER) IN lower(LS.INITIAL_REFERRER) ) >0 
WHERE ls.initial_referrer Like '%blue%decibal%'
ORDER BY xxxsales_key

Comment: basically I am looking to rewrite whatever I have done. Since the one I wrote seems to be a dumb one.

Comment: Delete everything, restore your backup, think again on a GOOD way to solve this, and if you do not have a backup, explain more clearly what you want. (Also: try to use the formatting options here on SO, which will make your question much easier to read!)

Comment: Hi Luuk, I can not be more clear than this. To make it simple, I have a table columns with URL. However, this URLs are not standard and some is messy. You might see two domain name in same URL like bing.google.com. we believe that the first domain is always valid as business rule. Also, other URL may sometime have messed data but there will be domain name. We have a lookup table which has got all the domain we use to market. Now we would like to lookup the URL and state that its google or Bing or Linkedin or...but the problem is how to acheive it.

Comment: Take a look at this [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6a44d6774ec37a6abe3968cdab603622)

Comment: Thanks, Luuk. Will work on it. Wonderful

Comment: Is this question about SQL Server OR Snowflake? Tagging it with both is just confusing. Please only use relevant tags to help people answer your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?  If not, I do believe that using the SPLIT as part of your parsing will help, since it then creates an array that you can manipulate.  This is an example for Snowflake SQL, not SQL Server.  They are both tagged in the OP, so not sure which you are looking for.

```
WITH x AS (
  SELECT REPLACE(url,'3A%','//') as url
  FROM (VALUES 
        ('https://blue.decibal.com.au/Transact?pi=9024&pai=2&ct=0&gi=1950&byo=true&ai=49&pa=289&ppt=0'),
        ('https://www.google.com/Transact?pi=9024&pai=2&ct=0&gi=1950&byo=true&ai=49&pa=289&ppt=0'),
        ('https3A%google.com/Transact?pi=9024&pai=2&ct=0&gi=1950&byo=true&ai=49&pa=289&ppt=0')) as x (url)
  )
SELECT split(split_part(split_part(url,'//',2),'/',1),'.') as url_array,
       array_construct('google') as google_array,
       array_construct('decibal') as decibal_array,
       array_construct('bing') as bing_array,
       CASE WHEN arrays_overlap(url_array,google_array) THEN 'GOOGLE'
            WHEN arrays_overlap(url_array,decibal_array) THEN 'DECIBAL'
            WHEN arrays_overlap(url_array,bing_array) THEN 'BING' END as domain_match
FROM x;
```

Comment: `split_part()` is a postgres function. In MSSQL you should use [`STRING_SPLIT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15), same for `array_construct()`, but i do not know the MSSQL alternative for that, and i am stop talking about `arrays_overlap()`

Comment: I should have noted that this is Snowflake SQL in my post.  I will edit the answer to reflect.  I neglected to notice that this had both Snowflake and SQL Server tagged.